# IIS Express re-compiling on almost every call after load of NuGet package

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

My web application has been working fine.  Just recently, I began trying to add Twitter Bootstrap to my project using NuGet (it doesn't appear that NuGet is the issue because the same thing happens if I add TB manually).  After doing so, I noticed that my app was misbehaving ... some items that I was displaying to a page from server-side cache were missing.

As I dug into this, I realized that my app was being re-loaded on almost every call.  I placed a break point in BundleConfig and sure enough ... almost every call, I'm hitting the break point.

If I uninstall the package, things start working fine again.

Furthermore, it doesn't seem to be just Twitter Bootstrap.  It seems that if I install any new packages into my system, this starts happening ... almost as if I'm pushing IIS Express over some sort of memory boundary?

I've tried to verify some of the normal IISExpress issues with re-compiling ... things being written into bin, etc.  But I don't see any activity on that front (and I'm definitely not explicitly writing anything there).  I'm not writing to web.config in code or anything either.

Last bit of information -- if I publish the non-working app to my QA server, everything works fine.  QA server is full-blown IIS -- not express.  This further confirms that nothing is being written into bin or messing with web.config.

**EDIT**
When I say I added Twitter Bootstrap, I mean that all I did was add it to the project.  I haven't even referenced it in any pages.  I haven't included it in my bundling/minification, etc.  It's basically just sitting there unused but still causes my app to recycle/recompile.

Comment: What about other dynamically compiled folders like App_Code, App_*Resources etc.?

Comment: No, I only have _bin_deployableAssemblies (which is not being changed), App_Start and bin ... everything else is your standard MVC stuff (Content, Controllers, Models, Views, etc)

Comment: If I were you I'd implement simple utility using FileSystemWatcher to see what is happening.

Comment: I can try that.  What's confusing to me though is the fact that this doesn't happen if I publish to the QA server.  If it were a matter of file-writing or a changing directory, I would think it would happen both locally as well as on the QA server.